# How to get notified about breaking changes in Azure services?

Tags: azure

I looked for this online and to my suprise I didn't find any relevant information.

We recently had a serious crash because one of Azure services had some breaking changes. This information was published on the service website and also I think shown as warning on Azure portal. The problem is that nobody checks the website if it's not needed and warnings can be overlooked.

I wonder if there is a mailing list or some other way to get emails only in case where there are some planned changes with serious impact on the services?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this is what I was able to find.

The best way to get notifications about potential breaking changes is to use Azure Service health available in Azure Portal - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview)

Here we can see planned certificate changes, some services being updated etc.

We can also configure for this to have notfications in Health Alerts section

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new it says:

"Get notified about when to revisit this page for updates by copying and pasting this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/api/search/rss?search=%22Release+notes+-+Azure+Active+Directory%22&locale=en-us into your RSS feed reader icon feed reader."

I didn't find anything about an email list, but I did find this tool that takes an rss feed and emails you.
https://blogtrottr.com/

Comment: Well this could be helpful. Nevertheless there is no tag available like ,,breaking changes". Maybe I'll contact Microsoft directly asking about this. For example this change https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/iot-hub-tls-certificate-update/ is a potential disruption in services having some serious impact on the users. I don't think it's stressed enough in the title or the tags